# Abstract class generator

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I'm at loss here. I want to refactor a part of the code that uses no abstract classes. I'm familiar with [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/). That converts a JSON file to the C# classes so it can be easily deserialized.

Is there a similar site/tool that accepts as input several C# classes and generates basic abstract classes based on those?
This would make the refactoring easier as I don't need to create all the different abstract classes.

Very simple example:

Input:

```
public class TestClass1
{
    public string TestID { get; set; }
    public string TestName { get; set; }
    public int TestValue1 { get; set; }

    public TestClass1()
    {

    }
}

public class TestClass2
{
    public string TestID { get; set; }
    public string TestName { get; set; }
    public int TestValue2 { get; set; }

    public TestClass2()
    {

    }
}
```

Output:

```
public abstract class ATestClass
{
    public string TestID { get; set; }
    public string TestName { get; set; }

    protected ATestClass()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You could use extract superclass features from resharper

Comment: `public abstract class AbstractBaseClass { }` – Done. In all seriousness though, why do you want to do that? Creating inheritance relations just for the sake of sharing common property definitions is generally a bad idea if there isn’t an actual inheritance property with those types.

Comment: Because of company policy I'm not able to use ReSharper unfortunately.

Comment: @poke: Main reason: to prevent conflicts when a property changes from type later on. If for example the TestID changes to an Int32, then I would need to change that in all the classes. With the abstract class it's changed once.

Comment: @poke We have many classes in our legacy-code that don´t have any inheritance, although from a design-perspective they *should* have. It´s absoluetely fine to extract a base-class to avoid annoying type-checking or even worse reflection to access the common properties, when you don´t know the exact type.

Comment: But an automated mechanism won’t know if the `TypeA.TestID` refers to the *same thing* as `TypeB.TestID`. And it’s likely that when a webservice changes its contract for one result that this does not necessarily mean that all other types that had an equally named property change as well.

Comment: @poke That´s true, however I think OP is just asking if for `TypeA` there´s a way to extract the superclass. Manually assigning extracted class this to `TypeB` however shouldn´t be a big issue. Anyway this would be the second step.

Comment: @HimBromBeere If you have a common type, then you have a type hierarchy. But that’s specific to what the types are about not what they look like. Inheritance and duck typing are two different concepts.

Comment: Using inheritance because refactoring tool like resharper is not allowed by policy. Rly?

Comment: Not because. I'm using inheritance for removal of duplicated code.

Comment: Well, Inheritance is not by default the best way to deduplicate code. But that is probably a different discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get something working pretty quickly if you use the Roslyn code analysis and code generation. Here’s a quick example how that could work. Note that this is somewhat fragile with detecting common properties since its based on the syntax instead of the actual semantics (making `string Foo` and `String Foo` incompatible properties). But for code that is actually generated by another code generator, this should work fine since the input should be consistent.

```
var input = @"
    public class TestClass1
    {
        public string TestID { get; set; }
        public string TestName { get; set; }
        public string OtherTest { get; set; }
        public int TestValue1 { get; set; }

        public TestClass1()
        {

        }
    }

    public class TestClass2
    {
        public string TestID { get; set; }
        public string TestName { get; set; }
        public int OtherTest { get; set; }
        public int TestValue2 { get; set; }

        public TestClass2()
        {

        }
    }";

// parse input
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(input);

// find class declarations and look up properties
var classes = tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot().ChildNodes()
    .OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>()
    .Select(cls => (declaration: cls, properties: cls.ChildNodes().OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>().ToDictionary(pd => pd.Identifier.ValueText)))
    .ToList();

// find common property names
var propertySets = classes.Select(x => new HashSet<string>(x.properties.Keys));
var commonPropertyNames = propertySets.First();
foreach (var propertySet in propertySets.Skip(1))
{
    commonPropertyNames.IntersectWith(propertySet);
}

// verify that the property declarations are equivalent
var commonProperties = commonPropertyNames
    .Select(name => (name, prop: classes[0].properties[name]))
    .Where(cp =>
    {
        foreach (var cls in classes)
        {
            // this is not really a good way since this just syntactically compares the values
            if (!cls.properties[cp.name].IsEquivalentTo(cp.prop))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }).ToList();

// start code generation
var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
var syntaxGenerator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(workspace, LanguageNames.CSharp);

// create base class with common properties
var baseClassDeclaration = syntaxGenerator.ClassDeclaration("BaseClass",
    accessibility: Accessibility.Public,
    modifiers: DeclarationModifiers.Abstract,
    members: commonProperties.Select(cp => cp.prop));

var declarations = new List<SyntaxNode> { baseClassDeclaration };

// adjust input class declarations
commonPropertyNames = new HashSet<string>(commonProperties.Select(cp => cp.name));
foreach (var cls in classes)
{
    var propertiesToRemove = cls.properties.Where(prop => commonPropertyNames.Contains(prop.Key)).Select(prop => prop.Value);
    var declaration = cls.declaration.RemoveNodes(propertiesToRemove, SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepNoTrivia);
    declarations.Add(syntaxGenerator.AddBaseType(declaration, syntaxGenerator.IdentifierName("BaseClass")));
}

// create output
var compilationUnit = syntaxGenerator.CompilationUnit(declarations);
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    compilationUnit.NormalizeWhitespace().WriteTo(writer);
    Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
}
```

This would generate the following output:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public string TestID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string TestName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class TestClass1 : BaseClass
{
    public string OtherTest
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int TestValue1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public TestClass1()
    {
    }
}

public class TestClass2 : BaseClass
{
    public int OtherTest
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int TestValue2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public TestClass2()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently using this to create the abstract classes. It's not perfect, but at least it saves a lot of time and that is the most important part currently.